# Getting each 'word' after every underscore in a string in Javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wanting to extract each block of alphanumeric characters that come after underscores in a Javascript string. I currently have it working using a combination of string methods and regex like so:

```
var string = "ignore_firstMatch_match2_thirdMatch";    
var firstValGone = string.substr(string.indexOf('_'));
// returns "_firstMatch_match2_thirdMatch"
var noUnderscore = firstValGone.match(/[^_]+/g);
// returns ["firstMatch", "match2" , "thirdMatch"]
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do it purely using regex? Best I've managed is:

```
var string = "ignore_firstMatch_match2_thirdMatch";
var matchTry = string.match(/_[^_]+/g);
// returns ["_firstMatch", "_match2", "_thirdMatch"]
```

but that returns the preceding underscore too. Given you can't use lookbehinds in JS I don't know how to match the characters after, but exclude the underscore itself. Is this possible?

Comment: Just use a capture group `_([^_]+)` and use `RegExp#exec` in a loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/4028085

Comment: Cheers for all the replies. I hadn't tried looping through groups because I thought there might be a 'cleaner' way to do it, so thanks for letting me know that loops and groups are the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group (`_([^_]+)`) and use [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) in a loop while pushing the captured values into an array:

```js
var re = /_([^_]+)/g; 
var str = 'ignore_firstMatch_match2_thirdMatch';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Note that using a [`string#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex defined with a global modifier `/g` will lose all the captured texts, that's why you cannot just use `str.match(/_([^_]+)/g)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `lookbehind` is not supported in JS the only way I can think of is using a group like this.

**Regex:** `_([^_]+)` and capture group using `\1` or `$1`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nF8tN5/1)**

```js
var myString = "ignore_firstMatch_match2_thirdMatch";
var myRegexp = /_([^_]+)/g;

match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
  document.getElementById("match").innerHTML += "<br>" + match[0];
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

```html
<div id="match">

</div>
```

---

An alternate way using `lookahead` would be something like this.

**But it takes long in JS. Killed my page thrice. Would make a good ReDoS exploit**

**Regex:** `(?=_([A-Za-z0-9]+))` and capture groups using `\1` or `$1`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nF8tN5/3)**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you assume you need regex? a simple split will do the job:

```
string str = "ignore_firstMatch_match2_thirdMatch";
IEnumerable<string> matches = str.Split('_').Skip(1);
```

Comment: I'm not assuming I need one, I know I don't. I'm trying to get better at using regex.